# R ddply with multiple variables

Tags: r, plyr

Here is a simple data frame for my real data set:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=rep(101:102,each=9),phase=rep(1:3,6),variable=rep(LETTERS[1:3],each=3,times=2),mm1=c(1:18),mm2=c(19:36),mm3=c(37:54))
```

I would like to first group by ID and variable, then for values(mm1, mm2, mm3), phase 3 is subtracted from all phases(phase1 to phase3), which would make mm(1-3) in phase 1 all -2, in phase 2 all -1, and phase 3 all 0.

R throws an error of "Error in Ops.data.frame(x, x[3, ]) :  - only defined for equally-sized data frames"
as I tried:

```
df1 <- ddply(df, .(ID, variable), function(x) (x - x[3,]))
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
The output should be look like this:

```
ID phase variable mm1 mm2 mm3
101  1      A     -2  -2  -2
101  2      A     -1  -1  -1
101  3      A      0   0   0
101  1      B     -2  -2  -2
101  2      B     -1  -1  -1
101  3      B      0   0   0
101  1      C     -2  -2  -2
101  2      C     -1  -1  -1
101  3      C      0   0   0
102  1      A     -2  -2  -2
102  2      A     -1  -1  -1
102  3      A      0   0   0
102  1      B     -2  -2  -2
102  2      B     -1  -1  -1
102  3      B      0   0   0
102  1      C     -2  -2  -2
102  2      C     -1  -1  -1
102  3      C      0   0   0
```

Comment: your formula should be something like `ddply(df, .(ID, variable), transform, mm1 = phase - mm1, mm2 = ...)`, but I can't figure out how you got from your sample data to the desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, took me a little bit to figure out what you want, but here is a solution:

```
cols.to.sub <- paste0("mm", 1:3)
df1 <- ddply(
  df, .(ID, variable), 
  function(x) {
    x[cols.to.sub] <- t(t(as.matrix(x[cols.to.sub])) - unlist(x[x$phase == 3, cols.to.sub]))
    x
} )
```

This produces (first 6 rows):

```
    ID phase variable mm1 mm2 mm3
1  101     1        A  -2  -2  -2
2  101     2        A  -1  -1  -1
3  101     3        A   0   0   0
4  101     1        B  -2  -2  -2
5  101     2        B  -1  -1  -1
6  101     3        B   0   0   0
```

Generally speaking the best way to debug this type of issue is to put a `browser()` statement inside the function you are passing to `ddply`, so you can examine the objects at your leisure.  Doing so would have revealed that:

1. The data frame passed to your function includes the ID columns, as well as the phase columns, so your `mm` columns are not the first three (hence the need to define `cols.to.sub`)
2. Even if you address that, you can't operate on data frames that have unequal dimensions, so what I do here is convert to matrix, and then take advantage of vector recycling to subtract the one row from the rest of the matrix.  I need to `t` (transpose) because vector recycling is column-wise.